# How to stop mails from going to /var/spool/mail/$USER folder and redirect them to the personal mail

Tags: html, shell

I've written a script which sends an `HTML` file through the mail using `mailx`.

My code is:

`mail_id=demo@host.com
cat /home/oretail/tmp/main.html | mailx -s "$(echo 'Subject Content-Type: text/html')" $mail_id`

The mail is going to `/var/spool/mail/root` folder.it's not coming to the specified e-mail id.

How to do i this?

`mail_id=demo@host.com
cat /home/oretail/tmp/main.html | mailx -s "$(echo 'Subject Content-Type: text/html')" $mail_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mailx does not deliver e-mail to the recipient, it is user agent. It puts a message to the queue to local MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) which can be sendmail, postfix, nullmailer,... or to remote SMTP server using following option

```
-S smtp=smtp://your_smtp_server.com
```

Messages in /var/spool/mail/root are most probably notifications about non delivered messages.